# Garbage collection causing application to skip frames due to object allocation

Tags: java, android, json, multithreading, parsing

I'm currently writing a simple application that performs an API call and displays the resulting data in a ListView. I'm using AsyncTask to download the JSON from the API in a separate thread and then transforming this JSON into a number of Product objects to be used in the ListView adapter.

Whenever I perform this operation however I get the following warning in the monitor:

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 405 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Obviously this results in the UI being unresponsive for a few seconds which isn't exactly ideal. I've figured out that this delay is due to garbage collection being performed due to there being too many objects being allocated to memory. The following message appearing multiple times is what has led me to believe this is the issue:

```
I/zygote: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 49.752ms for cause ObjectsAllocated
```

I'm aware that going from JSON > Java Objects requires some memory allocation however I wouldn't have thought allocating 235 objects to memory should have been too much of an issue.

Am I looking in completely the wrong place? Could it be my fetching of the data that is causing the slow down? Or perhaps my emulator doesn't have the memory allocated correctly?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I found the culprit, when transforming my JSON into Java objects there seems to be an issue where I'm creating massively bigger objects than I should be. For example, each Product has one or more Categories and Attributes. When parsing the JSON I'm monitoring how many of these have been read and how many are actually being saved with the following output occurring:

```
I/System.out: 2 categories in categories array for product Nieto Malbec, Mendoza
I/System.out: 2 attributes in attributes array for product Nieto Malbec, Mendoza
I/System.out: 9 categories being saved for product Nieto Malbec, Mendoza
I/System.out: 8 attributes being saved for product Nieto Malbec, Mendoza
```

This margin of error gets consistently worse as it goes further down the Product list:

```
I/System.out: 1 categories in categories array for product: Clearspring Organic Rapeseed Oil
I/System.out: 1 attributes in attributes array for product Clearspring Organic Rapeseed Oil
I/System.out: 360 categories being saved for product Clearspring Organic Rapeseed Oil
I/System.out: 315 attributes being saved for product Clearspring Organic Rapeseed Oil
```

I'm assuming I have some sort of runaway counter that is continually fetching more of the same Categories and Attributes for each Product however can't seem to track it down. I'm using the following code to fetch and parse the JSON:

```
protected ArrayList<Product> doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        int imageSize = params[0].intValue();

        // TO-DO ensure no JSON read can result in a null pointer reference
        // TO-DO change API call to adjust for screen size and JSOn transform to not use static size
        String url = "https://api.gousto.co.uk/products/v2.0/products?includes[]=categories&includes[]=attributes&image_sizes[]=" + imageSize;

        //Use JSONParser to download the JSON
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    url, "GET", new HashMap<String, String>());

        // Initialise empty arrays to be populated
        ArrayList<Product> productArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Category> categoryArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Attribute> attributeArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        try {

            // Get JSON array representing all elements within the data array
            JSONArray dataArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

            System.out.println("There are " + dataArray.length() + " product objects in the data array");

            // For each product
            for (int x = 0; x < dataArray.length(); x++) {

                // JSON object representing single product
                JSONObject productitem = dataArray.getJSONObject(x);

                // TO-DO initialise zero box limit to be used for null
                int boxLimit = 0;

                // Read the variables from each product
                String id = productitem.getString("id");
                String sku = productitem.getString("sku");
                String title = productitem.getString("title");
                String description = productitem.getString("description");
                double listPrice = productitem.getDouble("list_price");
                boolean isVatable = productitem.getBoolean("is_vatable");
                boolean isForSale = productitem.getBoolean("is_for_sale");
                boolean isAgeRestricted = productitem.getBoolean("age_restricted");
                boolean alwaysOnMenu = productitem.getBoolean("always_on_menu");

                // Check for null on box_limit
                if (!productitem.isNull("box_limit")) {

                    boxLimit = productitem.getInt("box_limit");

                }

                // Get JSON array representing category(s)
                JSONArray categoriesArray = productitem.getJSONArray("categories");

                System.out.println(categoriesArray.length() + " categories in categories array for product: " + title);

                // For each category in categoriesArray
                for(int i = 0; i < categoriesArray.length(); i++) {

                    // JSON object representing each category
                    JSONObject categoryObject = categoriesArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    // TO-DO initialise zero box limit to be used for null
                    int categoryBoxLimit = 0;

                    // Read the variables from the category
                    String categoryId = categoryObject.getString("id");
                    String categoryTitle = categoryObject.getString("title");
                    boolean categoryIsDefault = categoryObject.getBoolean("is_default");
                    boolean categoryIsRecentlyAdded = categoryObject.getBoolean("recently_added");
                    boolean categoryIsHidden = categoryObject.getBoolean("hidden");

                    // Check for null on box_limit
                    if(!categoryObject.isNull("box_limit")) {

                        categoryBoxLimit = categoryObject.getInt("box_limit");

                    }

                    // Initialise new Category and add to the ArrayList
                    Category category = new Category(categoryId, categoryTitle, categoryBoxLimit, categoryIsDefault, categoryIsRecentlyAdded, categoryIsHidden);
                    categoryArrayList.add(category);

                }

                // JSON array representing attribute(s)
                JSONArray attributesArray = productitem.getJSONArray("attributes");

                System.out.println(attributesArray.length() + " attributes in attributes array for product " + title);

                // For each attribute in attributesArray
                for(int y = 0; y < attributesArray.length(); y++) {

                    // JSON object representing a single attribute
                    JSONObject attributeObject = attributesArray.getJSONObject(y);

                    // String for null value on unit
                    String attributeUnit = "N/A";

                    // Read variables for
                    String attributeId = attributeObject.getString("id");
                    String attributeTitle = attributeObject.getString("title");
                    String attributeValue = attributeObject.getString("value");

                    // Check for null on unit value
                    if (!attributeObject.isNull("unit")) {

                        attributeUnit = attributeObject.getString("unit");

                    }

                    // Initialise new Attribute and add to attributes array
                    Attribute attribute = new Attribute(attributeId, attributeTitle, attributeUnit, attributeValue);
                    attributeArrayList.add(attribute);

                }

                // JSON object representing images
                JSONObject imagesObject = productitem.getJSONObject("images");

                // TO-DO initialise empty product image
                ProductImage productImage = null;

                // TO-DO Check for null on 1080
                if (!imagesObject.isNull("1080")) {

                    // JSON object representing single image
                    JSONObject imageObject = imagesObject.getJSONObject("1080");

                    // Read variables from image object
                    String imageSource = imageObject.getString("src");
                    String imageUrl = imageObject.getString("url");
                    int width = imageObject.getInt("width");

                    // ProductImage with variables
                    productImage = new ProductImage(imageSource, imageUrl, width);

                } else {

                    // ProductImage without variables
                    // TO-DO set as null and perform check on read
                    productImage = new ProductImage("Broken", "Broken", 0);

                }

                System.out.println(categoryArrayList.size() + " categories being saved for product " + title);
                System.out.println(attributeArrayList.size() + " attributes being saved for product " + title);

                // Add new product to products array
                productArrayList.add(new Product(id, sku, title, description, listPrice, isVatable, isForSale, isAgeRestricted, boxLimit, alwaysOnMenu, categoryArrayList, attributeArrayList, productImage));

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            System.out.println(e.toString());

        }

        return productArrayList;

    }
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at the memory monitor Android Studio provides? Click around in the app, see how much it increases, make a memory dump to see where most memory is located. Analyse these results and you should be able to make some performance improvements.

Comment: @TimKranen Thanks for the suggestion, I've figured out that it's definitely during my transformation from JSON to Java Objects that the memory is being allocated and therefore causing garbage collection to occur. Do you happen to know what the best way to do this is? Are there any popular third-party libraries?

Comment: Definitely! Moshi is a very good JSON serialization/deserialization library. Gson is another one. One key thing is the size of your objects though, the libraries won't help in reducing this size. Maybe you're deserializing objects that are too big? Could you post the code where you deserialize this? And maybe add Java models (objects) to it too? That way we can maybe figure out where exactly it's coming from.

Comment: Also if your objects are this big, how often are you transforming them from Json to java objects? And are you doing this on the main thread? Doing it on a different thread than the UI thread might help!

Comment: @TimKranen I've just realised that for some reason when I'm transforming my JSON one of the arrays within it is getting transformed 300+ times for some reason resulting in massive objects. Hopefully once I get to the bottom of this it should reduce the object size and in turn reduce the stress on the system. I'll post the code I'm using once I get back to my desk.

Comment: @TimKranen I've updated my original post with more clarity on the issue.

Comment: The culprit is definitely in the nested for loops. If you replace your JSON deserialization code with a library like Gson or Moshi you should be fine. There's no need to do it yourself in this day and age :)